# Merge two DataFrames if a value is not present in other DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two datasets as following
tf_df:

```
      Score    keyword
1  0.029827     olive
2  0.089482     London
```

df:

```
    keyword
1    olive
2    London 
3    USA
```

I need to append rows of `df` in `tf_df` if value of `df['keyword']` is not present in `tf_df['keyword']` and `tf_df` will be

```
      Score    keyword
1  0.029827     olive
2  0.089482     London 
3  NaN          USA
```

I have tried following code

```
for key_word in df['keyword'].to_list():
    if not keyword in tf_df['keyword']:
        tf_df.append(df[trend])
```

but it is giving `KeyError: 'keyword value'`. Can someone help me how to perform this task? Thank you

Comment: Use `df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates('keyword')`

Comment: Why not to try merge dfs as it is stated in the wording of your question?
```python
tf_df = tf_df.merge(df, on='keyword', how='left')
```

Comment: @ArtyomAkselrod `how='right'` , left will give only two rows

Comment: @SuhasMucherla true, my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `pd.merge`

```
tf_df=tf_df.merge(df,how='outer')

Score    keyword
1  0.029827     olive
2  0.089482     London 
3  NaN          USA
```